# Actionscript 3 - How do I remove the menu bar, scrollbar, to just have a blank popup?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, actionscript-3, flash

I have a auto open popup using Actionscript 3 and I don't want it to have any of the menu bars, scroll bars none of that, can anyone help me, here is my code:

```
var url:String = "https://www.google.co.uk/?gws_rd=ssl";    

var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);
try {

 navigateToURL(request, '_blank'); // second argument is target
} catch (e:Error) {

trace("Error occurred!");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use ExternalInterface. Call JS function `window.open` with next arguments:

```
ExternalInterface.call("window.open", 'http://stackoverflow.com','winname', 
'directories=no,titlebar=no,toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=no,width=400,height=350');
```

Comment: Replace all of your code that you have shown with my code.

Comment: That does nothing, there is no errors but no page is opening?

Comment: Do you embed the SWF file in the HTML?

Comment: Is there no way to do this in Adobe Flash just using Actionscript 3?

Comment: What do? Embed SWF or open new window?

Comment: Can i remove all the scrolbars and everything just using actionscript in flash?

Comment: You can do it only by using ExternalInterface.

Comment: Oh ok, is external interface done in flash or another program?

Comment: If you want to use an ExternalInterface you should click “Publish Settings...” and check HTML and SWF. Next, click File > Publish and open generated HTML in the browser.